# How to get the indexPath of the current cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, nsindexpath

I have currently trying to create a way to delete an item in a collection view at the indexPath of 1 back. So far i have used some help to create a function with scrollview did scroll to create a way to count which image the user is on by the current image method. I now need a way to count which cell the user is on. Here is my code>

```
 var currentImage = 0
   func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
let x = floor(myCollectionView.contentOffset.x / view.frame.width)
if Int(x) != currentImage {
    currentImage = Int(x)
    //print(currentImage)
}
if currentImage > 0 {
                for collectionCell in myCollectionView.visibleCells  as [UICollectionViewCell]    {
        let indexPath = myCollectionView.indexPath(for: collectionCell as UICollectionViewCell)!
       let indexPathOfLastItem = (indexPath?.item)! - 1
            let indexPathOfItemToDelete = IndexPath(item: (indexPathOfLastItem), section: 0)
            imageArray.remove(at: 0)
            myCollectionView.deleteItems(at: [indexPathOfItemToDelete])
            currentImage =  1
```

Comment: Based on the comments below my answer, your question is not at all what you should be asking. Why don't you update your question to be the real question - How to get the index path of the current cell so it can be deleted. Make that more clear in your question. Include relevant showing where you need to make this determination. None of what you really want has anything to do with printing visible cells in the `scrollViewDidScroll` method.

Comment: hmm I honestly thought to delete the item in a collectionview (1 item back) you need the indexPath of the item by dividing the contentsize by the width, and to tell which image the user is on.?

Comment: Yes, you do need the index path. Please read my comment again and please update your question accordingly. So far you've only updated the title. You need to redo the entire question. Much of your current question is irrelevant to what you are really trying to do.

Comment: Alright i have edited by question appropriately

Comment: Again, your question has nothing to do with scrolling or the `scrollViewDidScroll` delegate method. In which method do you actually want to delete the cell and determine its index path?

Comment: I really wish you would answer my question so people can help you. Again, for the nth time - In which method do you actually want to delete the cell and determine its index path? You have no need to count anything. You have no need to worry about scrolling. Just tell us how and when you wish to delete a cell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based more on the comments than your actual question, what you seem to want is to get the first visible cell's index path so you can use that path to delete the cell.

```
let visibleCells = myCollectionView.visibleCells
if let firstCell = visibleCells.first() {
    if let indexPath = myCollectionView.indexPath(for: collectionCell as UICollectionViewCell) {
        // use indexPath to delete the cell
    }
}
```

None of this should be used or done in the `scrollViewDidScroll` delegate method.

Comment: ok thanks but I still get something like this: http://imgur.com/a/6yI3p

Comment: oh thanks and how can I avoid this and only print the visible cells indexpath?

Comment: Avoid what? Your goal isn't clear. Your code is currently doing what you ask it to do - print all visible cells as the user scrolls the collection view.

Comment: ah I mean print the current cell indexpath not all

Comment: you see my goal is to print the cell in which the user is currently on because that cell is important to what I do next. I only need that individual cell.

Comment: What do you mean by "currently on"? There's no such concept.

Comment: so there is no way to find which cell the user is on, only you can just print them all?

Comment: Again, what do you mean by "currently on"?

Comment: i mean (remember this is horizontal scrolling collectionview, with paging enabled, one cell for the whole view, view width and height) I need to find the index path of oh lets say image 2 in the collection view (index 1) so I can do something with that

Comment: If it help clarify the problem rmaddy is pointing out; while you're scrolling between pages you have two visible cells. That's all the collection can tell you, "currently these two cells are both partially or completely visible". If you only want to consider one of them then you need to define how to choose between them to pick the "current" cell. Is that the cell the greatest % on screen, the most recently centered cell until it completely disappears, the cell most in the direction the user is scrolling, something else entirely?

Comment: i already know what image the user is on, but in order for me to do things like delete that image i need the indexpath, bc the func collectionview.delete( at: [indexPath]) look at this func right here, it identifies which image the user is on in the collectionview: var currentImage = 0
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let x = floor(myCollectionView.contentOffset.x / view.frame.width)
                       if Int(x) != currentImage {
                 currentImage = Int(x)

Comment: It you are trying to get the indexPath of "the current cell" so it can be deleted, why are you printing the list of visible cells in the `scrollViewDidScroll` method? The simplest approach is to simply access the first cell in the list of visible cells and use its indexPath at the actual point you wish to delete a cell. Don't do any of this while the collection view is scrolling.

Comment: hmm so I dont need the indexpath to lets say delete the last image the user was on in a collectionview

Comment: i really appreciate this guys, i did not know that the scrollview only loads 2 cells

Comment: Did you read my updated answer? It shows you exactly how to get the index path.

Comment: If you would read and answer the last comment I posted below your question then that can be answered.

Answer (score 5):

**[Updated for Swift 5.2]** Here's a slightly more succinct way than @rmaddy's answer (but that one works just fine):

```
guard let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems.first else {
    return
}

// Do whatever with the index path here.
```